Dialog with invisible background in Angular
My dialog component in Angular is appearing with a transparent background, as well as some other dialog details.
enter image description here
I defined the .mat-container background scss manually and it worked, but it is not ideal and there are some other details to be fixed.
I'm following the example in the Angular documentation, there is no different code, it should work.
This is the dialog:
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Hi {{data.name}}</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>
  <p>What's your favorite animal?</p>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="data.animal">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button (click)="onCancel()">No Thanks</button>
  <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="data.animal" cdkFocusInitial>Ok</button>
</div>

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dialog-amostra-rotina',
  templateUrl: './dialog-amostra-rotina.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dialog-amostra-rotina.component.scss']
})
export class DialogAmostraRotinaComponent {

  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogAmostraRotinaComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }


  onCancel(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

The call in another component:
  openDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogAmostraRotinaComponent, {
      width: '250px',
      data: {name: this.name, animal: this.animal}
    });
  
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      this.animal = result;
    });
  }


There is only a possibility if you haven't imported or installed the required ui packages. If you share full source code link then I can helpful. Thanks
